# How come I cannot add in jsp into google app engine in eclipse?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

How come I cannot add in jsp into google app engine in eclipse? I am using java. I was trying the tutorial on guestbook at google app engine and there was a step that say to create jsp into war folder but when i right click on war folder and then new, i can't find jsp to add in. So I would like to know is there anything wrong with my eclipse. Hope that i can get a reply. Thanks

Comment: can you elaborate on what you have tried, what is going wrong, what you are trying to do, etc?  right now there is not enough information for this question to be useful.

Comment: JSPs work just fine. I use them in my project.

Comment: What steps are you trying, and what happens when you try them? (I use JSPs on a stock Eclipse 3.6 with the Google Plugin for Eclipse installed. Works fine for me.)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean in the context menus "New" menu? If so, just select "New > File..." and type .jsp as the extension.